# Cuando estoy iniciando una class en Netbeans y luego me da la opción de implementar métodos, no los carga. que debo hacer?

Tags: netbeans, java-8

Ya eh agregado los metodos pero me sigue dando error. Puede ser que no no me cargue los metodos porque no exista la class o es por las dependencias intaladas?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: no me carga la opcion que te da la lamparita amarrilla de implement all abstract methods

Comment: Probe en el proyecto, clip derecho Build with Dependencies y me aparecio este mensaje de error : Fallo al ejecutar el objetivo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) en el proyecto IntegratorProject: Hay fallos en las pruebas.

Comment: luego fui a la carpeta  especificada en la compilación y me aparecio estos errores: Pruebas ejecutadas: 1, Fallos: 0, Errores: 1, Omitidos: 0, Tiempo transcurrido: 10,127 s <<<¡FALLO! - en com.portfolio.IntegratorProject.IntegratorProjectApplicationTests

Comment: contextLoads Tiempo transcurrido: 0,001 s <<<< ¡Error!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Causado por: org.springframework. beans . factory . BeanCreationException: Error al crear el bean con nombre 'entityManagerFactory' definido en el recurso de la ruta de clase [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:

Comment: La invocación del método init ha fallado; la excepción anidada es org.hibernate.AnnotationException: El atributo [com.portfolio.IntegratorProject.Security.Entity.Rol.id] fue anotado como enumerado, pero su tipo java no es un enum [int].

Comment: Disculpen soy muy novata como para resolverlo pero de allí se aprende.

Comment: Ana, todo lo que has agregado como comentarios, ponlo como edición a tu pregunta, ya que es información relevante. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.